# jQuery uncheck checkbox with name property

Tags: jquery, html

On an HTML page, I have a checkbox with the name property. I can't uncheck it with the name attribute.

HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="show_static_notify">
```

jQuery :

```
$("input[name='show_static_notify']:checkbox:not(:checked)");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$("input[name='show_static_notify']:checkbox").prop('checked',false);
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/h6Anu/)</kbd>

Comment: @john can u replicate that scenario where it failed than i can figure it out what's the problem .

Comment: don't know . but this worked form me .... check answer 
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="selectedIds\\[\\]"]:checked').prop('checked',false);

Answer (score 2):

what you are doing is to find the unchecked checkbox with given name

To uncheck the checkbox, use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$("input[name='show_static_notify']").prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

```
$("input[name='show_static_notify']:checkbox").removeAttr('checked');
```

or [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$("input[name='show_static_notify']:checkbox").prop('checked',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='show_static_notify']:checkbox").prop('checked',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me ..

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="selectedIds\\[\\]"]:checked').prop('checked',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this worked for me

$('input[type=checkbox][name=show_static_notify]').prop('checked', false);

Comment: @Daniel We have to specify input type  with name property. I tried without type and it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$("input[name='name_of_checkbox']:checkbox").prop('checked',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me .

$("input[name='half_session_type']").attr('checked',false);